# Get the Request Body in DRF API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am passing a value in my API POST request like this

```
{
  "reason": "string"
}
```

And my view is like this,

```
class UpdateReason(GenericAPIView):

permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = serializers.ReasonSerializer
queryset = Food.objects.all()

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.get_serializer().instance = service.update(self.get_object())
    return Response({"success": True})
```

serializer.py

```
 class ReasonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ("id", "reason")
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
```

In the `post`, I have to get the value of the `reason` and pass it to the service. How can I execute this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [`request.data.get('reason')`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/) :)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying, `self.get_serializer().validated_data` awhile ago.

Comment: Your welcome :) In fact, `validated_data` is used for "drf style" routes, [like here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances). But "post route" like yours comes from [Django class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views) (don't forget the drf is an overlay on Django). I suggests you to switch from `post()` to a `create()` method ; therefore you will have access to these serailizer features ;)